# Passing company logo to epdq payment page

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I am integrating epdq on my site and want to pass logo on epdq payment page I already sent logo to barklays bank and they upload our logo into their server and they provided us the link now I don't know how to pass logo to epdq payment page. I tried like this but its not working please help.

```
<?php
$amount = str_replace('&pound;', '', appthemes_get_price( $order->get_total(), $order->get_currency() ));
//str_replace('£', '', appthemes_get_price( $order->get_total())) * 100;
$hParams  = array();
          $hParams['LOGO']         = 'https://payments.epdq.co.uk/images/merchant/MYPSPID/llllo1.jpg';
      $hParams['ACCEPTURL']    = 'http://www.planetoftheads.com/bank-transfer-success/';
          $hParams['AMOUNT']       = $amount * 100;
          $hParams['CANCELURL']    = 'http://www.planetoftheads.com';
          $hParams['CURRENCY']     = 'GBP';
          $hParams['DECLINEURL']   = 'http://www.planetoftheads.com';
          $hParams['EXCEPTIONURL'] = 'http://www.planetoftheads.com';
          $hParams['LANGUAGE']     = 'en_US';
          $hParams['ORDERID']      = $order->get_id();
          $hParams['PSPID']        = 'MYPSPID';
          $hParams['WIN3DS']       = 'MAINW';

$aParams  = array();
          foreach( $hParams as $k=>$v ) {
               $aParams[]     = $k . '=' . $v;
          }
          $shain    = 'MY SHA-IN';
          $string   = implode( $shain, $aParams ) . "{$shain}";
          $enc_string= ( sha1( ( $string ) ) );
          //print $string;
 $enc_string;
?>
<input type="hidden" name="LOGO" value="https://payments.epdq.co.uk/images/merchant/epdq1100657/llllo1.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="ACCEPTURL" value="http://www.planetoftheads.com/bank-transfer-success/" />
<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="<?php echo $amount * 100;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="http://www.planetoftheads.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="DECLINEURL" value="http://www.planetoftheads.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="EXCEPTIONURL" value="http://www.planetoftheads.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="LANGUAGE" value="en_US" />
<input type="hidden" name="ORDERID" value="<?php echo $order->get_id(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="PSPID" value="MYPSPID" />
<input type="hidden" name="WIN3DS" value="MAINW" />
<input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="<?php echo $enc_string; ?>" />

<input type="submit" value="Pay Now">
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to give the relative image name and not the absolute url and see if it works. Something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="LOGO" value="llllo1.jpg">
```

I see that it automatically appends the logo value to this url https://payments.epdq.co.uk/images/merchant/MYPSPID/ .